# how to select specific range of <li> items between 2 id and sort them in Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML list as below :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" id="Own">
<li class="dropdown-header" id="datatables">Data Grid</li>
<li><a>Austria</a></li>
<li><a>China</a></li>
<li class="divider" id="firstDivider"></li>
<li class="dropdown-header"id="chart">Charts</li>
<li><a>Line Chart</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am adding new `<li>` dynamically inside my `<ul>` under each `<li>` with class `dropdown-header`.

For example under **Data Grid** I will add new list item **Belgium**

```
$( '<li><a>Belgium</a></li>' ).insertAfter( "#datatables" );
```

Now here comes the issue. When a new list item is added I want to sort my list alphabetically. So in my case it should be :

```
<li><a>Austria</a></li>
<li><a>Belgium</a></li>
<li><a>China</a></li>
```

I tried multiple approach how to select a specific range of **li** items and sort them but couldn't make it work.

here is my latest attempt :

```js
function asc_sort(a, b){ return ($(b).text().toUpperCase()) < ($(a).text().toUpperCase()) ? 1 : -1; }

//add new li item under Data Grid
$( '<li><a>Belgium</a></li>' ).insertAfter( "#datatables" );
//select all li items till li with id 'firstDivider', sort them and append to Own in the begining
$("#Own > li").nextUntil('#firstDivider').sort(asc_sort).appendTo("#Own");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" id="Own">
    <li class="dropdown-header" id="datatables">Data Grid</li>
    <li><a>Austria</a></li>
    <li><a>China</a></li>
    <li class="divider" id="firstDivider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header"id="chart">Charts</li>
    <li><a>Line Chart</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions please  what I am doing wrong ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```js
const countries = [
    'Austria',
    'China'
];
countries.push('Belgium');
countries.sort();
const items = countries.map(c => '<li><a>'+ c +'</a></li>');
$( "#datatables" ).append(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" id="Own">
    <li class="dropdown-header" id="datatables">Data Grid</li>
    <li class="divider" id="firstDivider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header"id="chart">Charts</li>
    <li><a>Line Chart</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I'm doing is:

1. Store all countries as a list. You can append new countries to that list at any time and always call `.sort()` to sort them alphabetically. It's more practical.
2. Sort the countries list via `.sort()` method;
3. Create new list item for each country in the list via `.map()` method (es6+ syntax with [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))
4. Append the all the list items to the `#datatables` container.